# Why doesn't sqlite3_next_stmt() iterate all statements?

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm working on an SQLite[3.6.20]-based C library, and I have encountered a behavior I don't understand.  When it comes time to close the database connection, I perform a preemptive rollback, and then I attempt to use `sqlite3_next_stmt()` to iterate over all unfinalized prepared statements and finalize them:

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

for (stmt = sqlite3_next_stmt(db, NULL);
        stmt;
        stmt = sqlite3_next_stmt(db, stmt)) {
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}
```

This indeed does iterate over several statements, and with a little instrumentation I can confirm that `sqlite3_finalize()` returns `SQLITE_OK` for each one.

In certain test cases, however, when I thereafter attempt to close the DB, I get SQLITE_BUSY (code 5) with an explanation that there are unfinalized statements.  And indeed, if at that point I call `sqlite3_next_stmt()` again, it returns a statement that my program likely did prepare, but which was not among those previously returned by `sqlite3_next_stmt()`.

So, am I wrong to think that the unfinalized statement should have been provided by `sqlite3_next_stmt()` on the first pass?  Is there something extra I should do to ensure that my statements can be cleaned up this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't trust `stmt` to contain anything meaningful (even to `sqlite3_next_stmt()`) after  it's been finalized.

Instead:

```
while (stmt = sqlite3_next_stmt(db, NULL)) 
{
  sqlite3_finalize(stmt); 
}
```

Comment: *facepalm* Kind of you to not say "You're a dork."  :-)

Comment: No, it's more "Oh, I remember when *I* did that..."